# Install only dependencies with pip from pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml

How do I only download dependencies from a pyproject.toml file that looks like this?

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["flit_core >=3.2,<4"]
build-backend = "flit_core.buildapi"

[project]
name = "colossalcyberadventureserver"
authors = []
dependencies = [
    "argparse ~= 1.4.0",
    "aioquic ~= 0.9.20",
    "sqlalchemy ~= 2.0.4",
    "argon2-cffi ~= 21.3.0",
    "uvloop ~= 0.17.0",
    "attrs ~= 22.2.0",
    "arcade @ https://github.com/pythonarcade/arcade/archive/refs/heads/development.zip",
    "asyncmy ~= 0.2.7"
]
requires-python = ">=3.10"
readme = "README.rst"
dynamic = ['version', 'description']

[project.urls]
Source = "https://github.com/AmitDIRTYC0W/ColossalCyberAdventureServer"

[project.scripts]
cca-server = "colossalcyberadventureserver.cca_server:cca_server"
```

What command would I need to run to only install the dependencies and not build the code in src/

Comment: Unrelated, but a project requiring Python 3.10 or later doesn't need to specify `argparse` as a dependency. `argparse` was added to the standard library in Python 3.2 (and concurrently to Python 2.7).

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to be using *flit*, you should be able to use a command like the following:

```
flit install --only-deps
```

***References***:

- https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/cmdline.html#cmdoption-flit-install-only-deps